s3 boto3 client can not set custom metedata
Once I try to set a custom metedata for my s3_file, uploading file sussessful but get metedata is {} with method head_object.
Here is portion of my code:
metadata = {
        'x-amz-meta-expiretime': f'{int(time.time() + 86400)}'  # 设置过期时间戳
    }
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_path)
    response = s3_client.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, s3_file_path,
                                     ExtraArgs={'Metadata': metadata})
    print(f"文件 {file_path} 成功上传到 S3 上的 {s3_file_path}")

    # 获取对象的头部信息，包括元数据
    head_response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_path)
    print(f"Metadata: {head_response['Metadata']}")

and got response:
Metadata: {}
I try to set metadata with ExtraArgs and expecting get the metadata with head_object method

When I run your code it works perfectly fine. The output is: 文件 x.py 成功上传到 S3 上的 foo Metadata: {'x-amz-meta-expiretime': '1715170033'}

It seems that our company's S3 service has some potential limitations or restrictions that prevent these operations.

Which Region are you using? I wonder if it's different in China?

No, it's because our S3 service  disabled some functionalities in the policies.
